# Android switch user based on lockscreen password

Tags: android, lockscreen, multi-user

Is there any way to switch between users using lockscreen password? I see MIUI has ability to switch between users using lockscreen password.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a while, no luck. Recently MIUI13 made this happen and I don't see people talking about it, nor do I know how to port this to AOSP...

Answer (score 0):

Only Xaomi phones can do this as far as I know. I haven't found other phones that can do this.